# Custom Camera Orientation issue in android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-orientation

I have an issue of orientation. My camera opens and save image in 90 sideways. How to change the orientation to potrait view. Please help me how to rectify it.

**PictureDemo.java**

```
package com.commonsware.android.picture;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PictureDemo extends Activity {
  private SurfaceView preview=null;
  private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
  private Camera camera=null;
  private boolean inPreview=false;
  private boolean cameraConfigured=false;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

//    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
//      Camera.CameraInfo info=new Camera.CameraInfo();
//
//      for (int i=0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
//        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
//
//        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
//          camera=Camera.open(i);
//        }
//      }
//    }

    if (camera == null) {
      camera=Camera.open();

    }

    startPreview();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (inPreview) {
      camera.stopPreview();
    }

    camera.release();
    camera=null;
    inPreview=false;

    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.options, menu);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.camera) {
      if (inPreview) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
        inPreview=false;
      }
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }

  private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                         Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
      if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
        if (result == null) {
          result=size;
        }
        else {
          int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
          int newArea=size.width * size.height;

          if (newArea > resultArea) {
            result=size;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return(result);
  }

  private Camera.Size getSmallestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
      if (result == null) {
        result=size;
      }
      else {
        int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
        int newArea=size.width * size.height;

        if (newArea < resultArea) {
          result=size;
        }
      }
    }

    return(result);
  }

  private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
    if (camera != null && previewHolder.getSurface() != null) {
      try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
              "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
        Toast.makeText(PictureDemo.this, t.getMessage(),
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      if (!cameraConfigured) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);
        Camera.Size pictureSize=getSmallestPictureSize(parameters);

        if (size != null && pictureSize != null) {
          parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
          parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width,
                                    pictureSize.height);
          parameters.set("orientation", "portrait"); 
          parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);

          camera.setParameters(parameters);
          //camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);

          cameraConfigured=true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void startPreview() {
    if (cameraConfigured && camera != null) {
     // camera.setDisplayOrientation(45);
      camera.startPreview();

      inPreview=true;
    }
  }

  SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                               int width, int height) {
      initPreview(width, height);
      startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      // no-op
    }
  };

  Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      new SavePhotoTask().execute(data);
      camera.startPreview();
      inPreview=true;
    }
  };

  class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
      File photo=
          new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                   "photo.jpg");

      if (photo.exists()) {
        photo.delete();
      }

      try {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());

        fos.write(jpeg[0]);
        fos.close();
      }
      catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
      }

      return(null);
    }
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsware.android.picture"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/cw"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".PictureDemo"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
</android.view.SurfaceView>
```

Comment: You need to find image Exif and need to rotate image as per Exif and have a look to this project : https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera , Another library : https://github.com/krschultz/android-camera-test

Comment: camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to store image im right rotetion.

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);
        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (Utility.isTabletDevice(mContext)) {
            // check Device is Tablet or Mobile
        }
        // opened camera is front or back
        if (frontCamera == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        } else {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        }
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
        final Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
        final Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        final File f = new File(imagePath);
        f.createNewFile();
        final FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
```

Comment: My preview starts with 90 only. I dont know how to rotate based on normal orientation

Comment: try to remove that line  parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");

Comment: and set this line in you project AndroidManifest file to this activty  android:screenOrientation="portrait"